# Serial communication reverse enginnering

Tags: serial-port

I am attempting to reverse engineer a device which utilises a serial line to communicate.

I have not currently been able to determine the baud rate of the serial line as of yet. Upon reading the data at a certain baud rate and converting it over to hex, I can see that some of the digits change each time I take a reading.

I am certain that each time I take a reading the device is performing the same action, and should therefore be outputting the same signal.

If I receive different digits each time I take a measurement, would this potentially be a trait of selecting an incorrect baud rate?

Comment: Use the proper tool for the job.  Use an oscilloscope to measure the baudrate.

Comment: Would you recommend an Oscilloscope or a Logic Analyser to help with this task? I don't own either yet! Thanks

Comment: Use the ***proper*** tool for the job. Use an oscilloscope (not a logic analyzer)) to ***measure*** the baudrate.